# Error [E0433] when `dyn` used with absolute path

Tags: rust, language-lawyer, dynamic-dispatch

I was playing with a `dyn` traits introduced in Rust 1.27 and stumbled into this compiler error:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve. Use of undeclared type or module `dyn`
 --> src\main.rs:1:30
  |
1 | fn _run0() -> Result<(), Box<dyn ::std::error::Error>> { Ok(()) }
  |                              ^^^ Use of undeclared type or module `dyn`
```

All other variants compile fine:

```
fn _run0() -> Result<(), Box<dyn ::std::error::Error>> { Ok(()) } // Error

fn _run1() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> { Ok(()) } // Ok

fn _run2() -> Result<(), Box<::std::error::Error>> { Ok(()) } // Ok
```

Is it intended behavior?

---

rustc 1.27.0 (3eda71b00 2018-06-19)

Comment: This is currently reproducible in the [playground](http://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2c51a1d4aaa645661bed78a37f130589&version=nightly&mode=debug) as well!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a backwards compatibility "gotcha" of the fact that `dyn` is a contextual keyword. Before the new syntax was added, you can write this code which uses `dyn` as a module name:

```
mod dyn {
    pub trait Error {}
}

fn example() -> Box<dyn ::Error> {
//                     ^ space doesn't matter
    unimplemented!()
}
```

This *cannot* stop compiling, so it must be parsed as a path component.

You can add parenthesis to be explicit:

```
fn example() -> Box<dyn (::dyn::Error)> { /* ... */ }
```

In the 2018 edition, you can use `crate` at the beginning of a path:

```
fn example() -> Box<dyn crate::dyn::Error> { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: @Tim not as of the current 2018 implementation. Seems deliberate.

Comment: The way I see it, a safe "fix" for this would involve deprecating `dyn` as a module name in one edition and prohibiting it in the next one. That might take a while.

Comment: @E_net4 Since 2018 is a preview at the moment, I don't see, why this shouldn't be possible for 2018.

Comment: On the other hand... that would lead to inconsistency with [Path Clarity](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/edition-guide/2018/transitioning/modules/path-clarity.html). The `::` should no longer be required at all.

Comment: @Tim Rust code in one edition must compile and have the same behaviour in the next. So no, we would need at least two editions for such a change to happen.